# Securing an API with shared secret

Tags: php, hash

I'm starting a REST API, and have begun researching hashing and shared salts/secrets.
I have successfully been able to generate a sha256 hash, sent it to my server via json and matched it to the stored hash.

Thats great and all, but i'm thinking, now that ive done this with json, the actual hash generated is still visible to everyone that wants it. I was under the impression that these hashes changed everytime you re-hashed a string using hash_hmac.

So how do i make sure that a random user wont find that little json snippet, grap the hashed key and start making API calls?

I might have misunderstood the concept completely, so any bumps is greatly appreciated.

Heres my "Client" page:

```
<?php
$key= hash_hmac('sha256', '66c74620db28603fe4bec7b0f3a8e53b', 'gwerganaevawe21_3faseghbamoirvQWD');
?>
<script>
$.getJSON( "domain.com/api/publicCourseSession.php?key=<?php echo $key;?>", function( data ) {
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
   console.log(val);
  });
});
</script>
```

And here is my publicCourseSession.php:

```
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $apikey =$_GET['key'];
    session_start();
    function hash_compare($a, $b) { 
        if (!is_string($a) || !is_string($b)) { 
            return false; 
        } 

        $len = strlen($a); 
        if ($len !== strlen($b)) { 
            return false; 
        } 

        $status = 0; 
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) { 
            $status |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]); 
        } 
        return $status === 0; 
    } 
    $currentnetwork = getCurrentNetwork();
    $currentkey = getNetworkApiKey(getNetworkId($currentnetwork));
    $currentsecret = getNetworkApiSecret(getNetworkId($currentnetwork));
    $currentkey= hash_hmac('sha256', $currentkey, $currentsecret);
    if (hash_compare($apikey,$currentkey)) { 
        $status='correct';
    } else {
        $status='not correct';
    }   

    $arr[] = ["key"=>$apikey, "currentkey"=>$currentkey, "correctkeys"=>$status];
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Typically the hmac is hashed with a shared secret key. That key is equivalent to a password in this case. The client accessing the API has the key and so does the server. A "man in the middle" shouldn't. All the hmac does is ensure that the message sent over hasn't been altered by someone else.

Comment: Also, just get an SSL certificate and there shouldn't be an issue with man in the middle attacks as the entire connection is encrypted. They are cheap or even [free](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Thanks for replying! Its all on SSL. ok, so the normal way of operation is to put all the responsibility of "hiding" the hashed key parameter with the client?   I am afraid that anyone can just inspect the clients code and start abusing the key that is right there in the json url.  If this is all good, then ill breathe easy =)

Comment: This last comment doesn't make much sense as the api_key is in the source code - HTTPS will ensure no one can see what's going in the page, but nothing prevents anyone from actually accessing the page and getting the secret_key.. (sorry, meant comment #2; comment #3 is correct, this doesn't prevents anyone from getting access to the key)

Answer (score 1):

You did well, that's step 1.

Thing is, you can't do security on the browser only - you should be providing the user with the secret key once he successfully authenticates himself using his credentials (like username/password). Once he has the secret key then he can use it to authenticate his requests and he no longer needs to send his username/password back and forth across the interwebs..

Goal of the secret key is to simplify authenticated requests once user started a session. To start a session you need to authenticate yourself first though, otherwise you'll be providing anyone with the secret key which defeats the purpose.

Also, key should be generated per user and expire after x amount of time so it can't be used indefinitely.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying! =)
This will be an api for public access to lections, so there is no username\password auth to play with.
I give my client the apikey for their network and the secret. and im at a loss as to how to really secure this down.. maybe ill just do like you say and require one of the clients admin users to logon to get the key. seems like a heavy way of operating API though :\

Comment: hmm.. what if you ask them to enter the key when they first access it and then use that key for all requests thereafter? The key thing is that the secret key can't be visible when you load a page, otherwise everyone will be able to get it.